# Python - parsing configuration file - flow control

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a python 2.7 script to parse through a configuration file.  The configuration file has standard settings but not all settings are populated.  I've been able to extract the values for a single section, but when I added additional entries my script logic fails.  I am thinking I could use the attributes (RuleName, Next) in the configuration file to break thinks up but I can't think of how to accomplish this.  Below is a sample of what the configurations look like.

**Configuration File**

```
    RuleName "Rule 1"
    value1 = "some value"
    value2 = "some value"
    value3 = "some value"
    value4 = "some value"
Next
RuleName = "Rule 2"
    value1 = "some value"
    value2 = "some value"
    value3 = "some value"
Next
RuleName = "Rule 3"
    value1 = "some value"
    value2 = "some value"
    value3 = "some value"
    value4 = "some value"
    value5 = "some value"
Next
```

Here is the logic of my script.  Any suggestions would be helpful.  This is my first attempt to write a more complex script with Python.  I am sure there are more sophisticated ways to due this but I'd like to keep it relatively basic as I learn python.

Thank You!

```
for line in lines:
    n = line.lstrip()
    if n.find(rulesetting1) != -1:
        pos = len(rulesetting1)
        rulevalue1 = n[pos:]
    elif n.find(rulesetting2) != -1:
        pos = len(rulesetting2)
        rulevalue2 = n[pos:]
    elif n.find(rulesetting3) != -1:
        pos = len(rulesetting3)
        rulevalue3 = n[pos:]
    elif n.find(rulesetting4) != -1:
        pos = len(rulesetting4)
        rulevalue4 = n[pos:]
    elif n.find(rulesetting5) != -1:
        pos = len(rulesetting5)
        rulevalue5 = n[pos:]
    elif n.find("Next") != -1:
        Start cycle over?
```

What about searching for "Next" and then starting the cycle over.  Eventually I want to write this to a CSV file, but I need to get this flow down first.

Comment: I think you need another variable to indicate the state you are in. For example, before any line read, set the state to `"WAITING_RULE"`, upon `"RuleName"` line read, set the state to `"READING_RULE"`. Upon `"Next"` line read, set the state back again. If you only want to load certain rules, skip the `"RuleName"` lines that you doesn't want. The state variable determines whether a `value = "value"` line should be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a dictionary to me.

```
optionsdict = dict()

curkey = None
for line in optionsfile:
    if line.strip().startswith("RuleName"):
        curkey = line.split("=")[1].strip()  # whatever's after the =
    elif line.strip() == "Next":
        pass  # not sure what you're doing with the Next lines...
    else:
        option, value = map(str.strip, line.split("="))
        optionsdict.setdefault(curkey, {})[option] = value
```

That said, it seems like it'd be easier to use a more standard format that comes batteries included, if you're making this all up anyway.

```
# configfile.ini
[Rule 1]
value1 = "some value"
value2 = "some value"
value3 = "some value"
value4 = "some value"
[Rule 2]
value1 = "some value"
value2 = "some value"
value3 = "some value"
value4 = "some value"
[Rule 3]
value1 = "some value"
value2 = "some value"
value3 = "some value"
value4 = "some value"
value5 = "some value"
```

```
# Python script

from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()
config.read_file("path/to/configfile.ini")
config["Rule 1"]["value1"]  # "some value"
```

This uses the [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) package to parse your options.

Comment: Configparser states "The configuration file consists of sections, led by a [section] header and followed by name: value entries," which my config file doesn't necessarily follow this format.  Is it possible to have a loops iterate within another loop and use line values such as "edit" and "next" as a delimiter of when to start and stop the iteration?  I want to capture all the data which may or may not have all of the associated values.

Comment: I don't see any of that in your example. Can you give me an example config file?

Comment: Please see the section called Configuration File.  Basically each section is delimited by RuleName and Next.  The details of the rule fall between these two delimiters.  I have roughly 50 rules which I need to iterate through.

Comment: Yeah I read that, I'm not sure how that's relevant. There doesn't appear to be any sort of looping or etc in your question

Comment: In the above configuration file I have 3 rules shown.  Each rule contains values/settings.  I am able to loop through a configuration file with only one rule.  When I add additional rules my looping fails to keep each rule's settings separate.  Ultimately I'd like to be able to parse this configuration file and output the rules and associated values to a CSV file.  There is a set number of setting for each rule, but not all settings are fully populated.  Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Found this old question, one more solution to this problem would be to use[TTP](https://github.com/dmulyalin/ttp) to parse above text, here is the code:

```
from ttp import ttp
template = """
<input load="text">
Next
RuleName = "Rule 2"
    value1 = "some value"
    value2 = "some value"
    value3 = "some value"
Next
RuleName = "Rule 3"
    value1 = "some value"
    value2 = "some value"
    value3 = "some value"
    value4 = "some value"
    value5 = "some value"
</input>

<group name="{{ rule_name }}">
RuleName = "{{ rule_name | ORPHRASE }}"
<group name="data">
    {{ key }} = "{{ value | ORPHRASE }}"
</group>
</group>
"""

parser = ttp(template=template)
parser.parse()
print(parser.result(format="json")[0])
```

above code will print:

```
[
    {
        "Rule 2": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "key": "value1",
                    "value": "some value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "value2",
                    "value": "some value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "value3",
                    "value": "some value"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Rule 3": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "key": "value1",
                    "value": "some value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "value2",
                    "value": "some value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "value3",
                    "value": "some value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "value4",
                    "value": "some value"
                },
                {
                    "key": "value5",
                    "value": "some value"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```